# WIX adding shortcut to a website or url location using wix and choose custom icon for that shortcut

Tags: wix, icons, shortcut

I want to add a shortcut to the start menu group with following specifications:

1. It should point to a website, say www.xyz.com
2. It should have some custom icon
3. I need to pass some parameters to it, like www.xyz.com?lang=XXXX.
   Where XXXX is language code e.g. 1033, 1036, etc. and it's dependent on the language chosen by the user for my application.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

if the website is always the same you could try including one shortcut.url inside your package for each language that you support and install only the one for that specific language on the disk. 
this way you could also control the shortcut that gets used for the .url file.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but this is not what I wanted.
This will install a shortcut which will always point to the website with only one language, irrespective of what language chosen in the application. The shortcut is supposed to send the language selected in the application.

Comment: sorry if I wasn't clear enough - the solution that i propose is to include one .url for every language and then filter the one that gets installed depending on the language the user chooses.

Comment: Sorry for delayed reply, but, This will also put a shortcut with one language only - in which the software is installed - right?
And what I wanted was, that shortcut should point to the language selected in the application and not installed language. Anyways, I have a working solution now. Thanks for the efforts :)

Answer (score 0):

I found a work-around for this problem.
I made an executable which parses stored language and then calls `ShellExecute` to start the default browser with required url and language option. I added a shortcut to this executable in the start menu, icon was included in the executable itself.